# Rally: how to pull latest testresult from a specific testset

Tags: date, datetime, sdk, rally

I am trying to use the following code to get a pie chart for the latest testresult from a particular testset.

```
pieconfig = {
type: 'TestCaseResult',
attribute: 'Verdict',
query: rally.sdk.util.Query.and(['TestSet = "' + testsetDropdown.getValue() + '"','Date < "2012-11-01"'])
            };
var pieChart = new rally.sdk.ui.PieChart(pieconfig,rallyDataSource);
pieChart.display("pieChartDiv");
```

In this code I've put today's date manually, but I want to make this query as of a  generic type which should pull the latest testresult from a specific testset. Any hints...? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rally has a nice DateTime format that formats dates to whatever you want. Here's the reference you can use: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/datetime.

If you always want the current day in the year-month-day format, you can do this:

```
var dateQuery = 'Date < ' + rally.sdk.util.DateTime.format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Then your query will look something like this:

```
query: rally.sdk.util.Query.and(['TestSet = "' + testsetDropdown.getValue() + '"', dateQuery])
```

EDIT: Now I see what you mean by grabbing the latest TestCaseResult. You don't actually need the Date conditional in your query. What you need to add is a couple of options to your pie config.

```
var pieconfig = {
    type: 'TestCaseResult',
    attribute: 'Verdict',
    query: '(Test Set = "' + testsetDropdown.getValue() + '")',
    order: 'CreationDate desc',
    pagesize: 1
};
```

This will sort by the Creation Date in descending order, which means the most recently made TestCaseResult will be on top. Setting a pagesize to 1 means you'll always get the most recent result.

This also solves the issue of not getting test case results of the current day. The previous query will get all TestCaseResults from today at 12:00AM backward. So any test case results made in the current day will not be included.

Let me know if that doesn't work out for you. I'm pretty new to the Rally SDK1 query system.

Comment: But isn't this gonna pull all previous testresults? I only want to fetch the latest testresult.

Comment: Sorry about the gap in the edited answer and this comment, give the edited answer a whirl and see if it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it. Also, is there any api documentation for rally 1.x sdk. Cuz i see lots of functionalities(methods,properties) in sample apps which are not mentioned in the rally developer portal? Thanks.